# SQL injection to drop/empty table

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to drop/empty table using user inputs.

My SQL code is
`$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' and password = '$password'"`;

I am typing `or 1=1#` to login without username and password which works perfectly!

Any idea how can I drop/empty the contain of table (users)?

I have tried so may ways like:

`or DROP TABLE users`;
 `or DROP TABLE users`;
 `or DROP TABLE users`

Comment: `'; drop table users;'` should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: I used query() instead of multi_query()

multi_query() can take more than one queries at one time.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL injection that you are trying to do use the closing of the request, by closing the argument with `'`. So, you should begin by closing the actual ' before trying to do something else.

For example :

```sql
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ''; here do what you want;'';
```

Here, the name was `'; here do what you want;'`. Composed of:

- `'` closing `WHERE` section
- `;` closing the request that is sensitive to SQL injection
- You SQL request, for you `DROP TABLE users;`
- `'` to re-open what we closed at the begin

Comment: Did not work with me

Comment: what do you mean with "did not work" ?

Comment: I used in my code query() instead of multi_query(). I have to used multi_query().